# build-impl.xml error when using NetBeans

Tags: java

Ok, so I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927132/receiving-java-result-1-from-program-with-no-stack-trace) question yesterday, and I still haven't found my solution, but I luckily I have enabled more logging and I am receiving this error message:

```
C:\....\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1039: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\....\nbproject\build-impl.xml:804: Java returned: 1
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor245.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor245.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor245.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 minutes 8 seconds)
Could not load class (org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.repository.MavenRepository) for type mavenrepository
Could not load a dependent class (jdepend/xmlui/JDepend) for type jdepend
Could not load a dependent class (javax/media/jai/PlanarImage) for type image
Could not load class (org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.repository.MavenRepository) for type mavenrepository
Could not load a dependent class (jdepend/xmlui/JDepend) for type jdepend
Could not load a dependent class (javax/media/jai/PlanarImage) for type image
```

I am using NetBeans 8.1 with only JDK 8 (both 32bit). I am also using Windows 8. I have performed a clean on the build-impl.xml from within NetBeans and I am still seeing this issue. Is it related to Ant somehow? I don't even really know what Ant is or does.

Here is the output for line 1039:

```
<j2seproject1:java>
    <customize>
        <arg line="${application.args}"/>
    </customize>
</j2seproject1:java>
```

Here is the output for line 804

```
        <java classname="@{classname}" dir="${work.dir}" failonerror="${java.failonerror}" fork="true">
            <jvmarg line="${endorsed.classpath.cmd.line.arg}"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=${runtime.encoding}"/>
            <redirector errorencoding="${runtime.encoding}" inputencoding="${runtime.encoding}" outputencoding="${runtime.encoding}"/>
            <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs}"/>
            <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs.ide}"/>
            <classpath>
                <path path="@{classpath}"/>
            </classpath>
            <syspropertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="run-sys-prop."/>
                <mapper from="run-sys-prop.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
            </syspropertyset>
            <customize/>
        </java>
```

Comment: Simply delete the line of build impl.xml at which error occurs and run it again

Comment: well i wouldn't be deleting one single line, its an xml file, are you asking me to delete the entire section?

Comment: No only the line at which error is occuring not the xml file

Comment: build-impl.xml:1039 Click on this line and delete it

Comment: it wont build of course, since there is an </j2seproject1:java> and no opening <j2seproject1:java>...`<j2seproject1:java>` is what is on line 1039

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I have created a new glassfihs server and then it has worked...